# Visual Studio Solution with Multiple Projects: Reference Paths

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Solution that contains three projects:

- A Windows Service which will read Data from a SQLite Database to perform actions
- A Winforms App which will provide a method of configuring the behaviour of the Service (by updating the SQLite Database)
- A Class Library Project to abstract all database access away from the service and the config app (making it easier in the future to update anything having to do with the database without having to hunt down queries in the other two projects)

All of these projects are in the same solution, and I have added references from the Winforms App and the Service to the class library. In both projects I am able to see the classes from the class library and interact with them, but I am having an issue. I have created the database in the /Resources/ directory of my class library project (because to me the "common" project is the only sensible place to store the common database), however whenever I attempt to access the database in the Winforms app, it is not returning data that I know is in there. Since System.Data.SQLite has the default behaviour of creating an empty database file if the file isn't found (an odd choice in my opinion), I can't even go back and tell if the database exists or not.

This leads me to suspect that I am not understanding properly how files from one project are referenced in another. Here is what my project looks like:

[image: Screenshot of the Solution Manager in VS]

WorkModeCommon Contains the classes SQLiteDatabase and ScheduleManager, where ScheduleManager has a SQLiteDatabase() and SQLiteDatabase interacts with Resources/WorkModeSchedules.s3db

Both the WorkModeConfigApp and the WorkModeService have a WorkModeCommon.ScheduleManager(), which should in theory take care of all of the database interaction.

Do I have a major flaw in my design, or could someone point me to a resource which could help me solve the problem I'm having?

Comment: When you call a method from another project, the code is run in the context of the calling project, not the called project.  This is why, for example, when you reference `ConfigurationManager` you have to be careful that the settings are in the project that is currently executing, not the project containing the class file that makes a reference to `ConfigurationManager` - a common mistake.

Comment: Do you have any advice about how to store/reference resources so that they can be accessed from a common location on any system where the program has been installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks, I've solved my problem. What I did is include a copy of the DB file in each project, and set the "Copy To Output Directory" property on all but one of those instances (the "Common" project) to "Do Not Copy". After that I changed the output directory for all three projects to the same directory (more specifically, I created centralized Debug and Release directories and pointed the proper build configurations to the proper directories). I am now able to test successfully using a single DB file and a centralized class library!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what's happening.
When you reference the common class library, it's simply using the .dll output as the reference, since it's the only output.
However, if you right-click on the .s3db file and go to its Properties, you can set its `Copy to Output Directory` setting to `Copy if newer`, that way the database file itself is in the output directory, so the .dll file can see it.
Now, when your form or service access the .dll file from the output directory of your common class library project, it'll reference the .s3db file, too, so then they'll all see the same data.

Whether this is a good design or not depends on your needs.
If the form and the service are both looking at the same data at the same time, then you have to make sure they're at least looking at the same file, not at their own copies of the .s3db file.
If it's just the form or the service accessing the database, I'd be ok with it, but since multiple processes (the form and the service) are accessing it, a common database server is a good choice.

Comment: In most instances, only the service will be accessing the database, and the service will only read the database, it will never write to it. The goal is that the config App will be run once initially, and then extremely infrequently after that.

Answer (score 1):

Compiled classes are visible to outside assemblies that reference them as long as their visibility is Public (with some exceptions).  Non-compiled files are a different story. You can specify the build action as "embedded resource", which will allow you to access the file from referencing assemblies, albeit in a read-only fashion.  The other option, and likely what you want, is to specify "copy to output directory" as either "copy always" or "copy if newer."  This will copy the file to the output directory at build time.

Answer (score 1):

When you start debugging your WorkModeConfigApp, the app runs from its bin\debug directory and has no way to reach the resource directory of the class library. Simply referencing the class library doesn't means that VS copy the resource directory of the class library inside the bin/debug of the Config app. If you set the Copy Local = true for the class library VS will copy the compiled DLL inside the bin\debug of WorkModeConfigApp but doesnt' copy the content of the resource directory

On the other way, you could set the property `copy to the output directory` for the .s3db file, in this way the file and its directory will be copied in the bin\debug of the WorkModeConfigApp. But this will be the source of other problems because during debug your test database risk to be overwritten from the one coming from the class library.

I think that your best option is to save inside the configuration files of the service and of the config app where to locate this file and don't mess with the aforementioned property.

We are talking about a Database so probably in the config file for App and service you need to add a connection string. You could add the required nodes to your App.config, see the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.MyDatabaseConnection"
            connectionString="Data Source=C:\ProgramData\MyAppName\/WorkModeSchedules.s3db;Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You could then access this value using one these methods:

```
string cnnString1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnection"];
string cnnString2 = Properties.Settings.Default.MyDatabaseConnection;
```

(The ConfigurationManager method requires the reference to System.Configuration assembly)

Comment: I think your idea about saving the DB location in the config file is a great idea, but I have no idea where the DB would end up in relation to the App/Service when installed. Do you have any advice on how to reference it in the config files?

Comment: I can't help on `Where to put your DB` (usually it's a location accessible to both the ConfigApp and the service with read/write permissions like the %APPDATA% folder). For the configuration file see my update.